# synchronizing a database insert and select behind a web service

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm struggling to figure out how to solve this problem in mule using the studio and thought that perhaps reaching out to the good users of SO may be of some help.

I have a simple webservice that takes a request from a client. this request will preform an insert into a database table, effectively using this database as a message queue. A separate process periodically polls this table, performs additional processing on the message, and then writes results to an output table. the database insert and subsequent select will be linked by a a correlationId that I can pass along to ensure I get the result for the message that was sent. Unfortunately, the software this will integrate with requires this pattern to work correctly.

Here's the workflow that is needed:

**HttpRequest -> insert record into a table -> wait(or poll/retry/etc?) until a record is written to another table by a separate process(with the same correlationId) -> return data from this other table back to the httpRequest**

here's a sample flow that is as close as i've been able to get with this. Oddly enough, this flow does actually return a payload, however it seems to always be "1". i can't quite see how to make this flow retry the database query until a row exists and then return the resulting row.

How should i be synchronizing 2 database calls? is this possible within mule perhaps with a different combination of components?

Thanks.

```
<flow name="mainFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="CXF" configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" serviceClass="kansas.MuleTestServiceImpl"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into tblRequest (id, correlationId) values(#[payload], #[message.correlationId])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <until-successful objectStore-ref="MyObjectStore" maxRetries="5" millisBetweenRetries="2000" doc:name="Until Successful" > <!-- failureExpression="???" -->
        <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select correlationId,msgResponse from tblResponse where correlationId = #[message.correlationId]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </until-successful>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/> <!-- why is payload always = 1? -->
</flow>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mule is great tool but it makes your life too easy. Sometime so easy that you forget simple things.

In your case you forgot that payload is one object which is result of last component. Think about flow as rails with just one cart. Whatever you load on last station is delivered to the next one. And then process repeats. What was originally delivered to the station does not matter. Matters what you load.

In your case first database component has original payload from CXF and stores something in the database. It returns result of the INSERT statement which is 1 - one row is inserted. So our payload keeps deliver new cargo - 1.

But you need original payload from CXF. Where it is? It is gone - we have only one flow, one pair of trails, one cart.

What to do in this situation? Keep required information not in the cart but somewhere else. For example in flow variables. Store original payload in some variable and then restore it when it required again. Like this

```
<flow name="mainFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="CXF" configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" serviceClass="kansas.MuleTestServiceImpl"/>
        <set-variable variableName="storedPaylod" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Store original payload"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into tblRequest (id, correlationId) values(#[payload], #[message.correlationId])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.storedPaylod]" doc:name="Restore Payload"/>
    <until-successful objectStore-ref="MyObjectStore" maxRetries="5" millisBetweenRetries="2000" doc:name="Until Successful" > <!-- failureExpression="???" -->
        <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select correlationId,msgResponse from tblResponse where correlationId = #[message.correlationId]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </until-successful>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/> <!-- why is payload always = 1? -->
</flow>
```

[image]

Good idea will be to check that first database component really returns 1 - record is inserted. Do this, produce alerts on the error, and then restore original payload and continue your flow.

Comment: Thank you for this. The analogy certainly helped greatly and will allow me to get around some of the problems with this. I think i may have done a poor job explaining the problem i have. The main issue i have is "synchronizing 2 database calls" basically, the "until successful" component (or perhaps a different component?) must wait until a record is inserted by a separate process, and the resulting insert should become the payload.

Comment: In this case you should poll or some other periodic process which should check that record is inserted. Then you should do dependent insert. Trying to insert in hope it will work but mostly expecting exception is not good idea.  This new insert on "perhaps" may, perhaps, lock good one and you will be in dead lock.

Comment: thanks alex, mostly what i'm trying to do is correlate a request message placed in the database and then have the requester wait until a message  is polled from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to avoid killing the actual value of your payload after the database insert is to make use of the Message Enricher processor.

try this code below:

```
<flow name="mainFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" serviceClass="kansas.MuleTestServiceImpl" doc:name="CXF"/>
    <enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[flowVars.insertResponse]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into tblRequest (id, correlationId) values(#[payload], #[message.correlationId])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
    </enricher>
    <flow-ref name="dbSelectSubFlow" doc:name="dbSelectSubFlow"/>

    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="dbSelectSubFlow">
    <until-successful objectStore-ref="MyObjectStore" maxRetries="5" millisBetweenRetries="2000" doc:name="Until Successful">
        <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select correlationId,msgResponse from tblResponse where correlationId = #[message.correlationId]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </until-successful>
</sub-flow>
```

Comment: the problem i have is not actually with killing the value with the payload. the problem i have is correlating a database insert and select.